# Azure Tables vs Blob

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I move my web application to Azure.

My application has many small (till 1 Mb, approx. 100 kb per file) files (image formats). Each file has the unique name (which can be found by name). Right now there is a simple folder on web hosting with 1000x files. What is more effectively to use - Azure Tables or Blob ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blob service would be the best choice for this scenario. Couple things to consider:

1. Since the partition key is down to the blob name, we can load balance access to different blobs across as many servers in order to scale out access to them.
2. If you need to, you could make your container(s) public, allowing unauthenticated access to the blobs.
3. If #2 is not desired, you could still use Shared Access Signatures to make your blobs downloadable with a browser or another HTTP client that is not aware of Azure Storage.